# How to call an element of an object created with a magrittr pipe?

Tags: r, magrittr

Using the magrittr piper operator we perform manipulation on a vector.

```
strings <- "a b c"
strings %>% strsplit(" ") # Here we get a list 


> strings %>% strsplit(" ")
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

But let's assume that we would only like to get the single element of this list. This would require us to (example to get the first element):

```
(strings %>% strsplit(" "))[[1]][1] # Notice the braces around the expression..
```

Now to my question: Is there a way to use the pipe operator without the need of putting the whole expression in braces? It would be more transparent, I think, if we would not have to write it into a temporary variable or use brackets but use some kind of a special pipe operator.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or also:

`strings %>%  strsplit(" ") %>% { .[[1]][1] }`

which would be the same as

`strings %>%  strsplit(" ") %>% .[[1]]  %>% .[1]`

Compare the timings:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  (strings %>% strsplit(" ") %>%  unlist %>%  first)
  ,(strings %>%  strsplit(" ") %>% { .[[1]][1] })
  ,(strings %>% strsplit(" ") %>% map_chr(1))
)
# Unit: microseconds
#                                          expr     min      lq       mean     median       uq      max    neval
# (strings %>% strsplit(" ") %>% unlist %>% first)   280.270 288.363  301.9581 295.4685 305.1395  442.511   100
# (strings %>% strsplit(" ") %>% {     .[[1]][1] })  211.980 219.875  229.4866 226.3875 235.6640  298.429   100
# (strings %>% strsplit(" ") %>% map_chr(1))         682.123 693.965 747.1690 710.1495 752.3875  2578.091   100
```

Comment: oh. that was exactly what I needed... Of course, why didn't I think of the dot... Thanks!

Comment: @akrun You are right, microbenchmark is not fair, but it shows, that there is an overhead from dplyr which we can avoid. Would you agree to that?

Comment: I meant microbenchmark is useful for big datasets.  Here the string is only having 3 elements split up

Comment: Ah ok, misunderstood you. Since the example is so small, e.g. system.time/proc.time would not show the difference. If there is any other benchmarking tool for smaller examples let me know, I am just used to microbenchmark...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `map_*()` functions from the `purrr` package :

```
strings %>% strsplit(" ") %>% map_chr(1)
[1] "a"
```

The `*` refers to the type you want as output and the `1` to the position in the list.

This option could be use with vectors

```
> c("a b c", "d e f") %>% strsplit(" ") %>% map_chr(1)
[1] "a" "d"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do

```
strings %>% 
      strsplit(" ") %>%
      unlist %>%
      .[1]
#[1] "a"
```

Comment: Well this would not work if we would like to get a second or a 100th object since it uses a function first to call only the first object. right?

Comment: @WojciechF  I thought you wanted the first element.  That is the reason I used the inbuilt function.  Otherwise, just subset by index `.[1]` or `.[2]`

Comment: U R right I wrote about the first element but I meant to get a specific element.  I changed my question to be more general.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `extract` after `unlist`your list like this:

```
strings %>% 
  strsplit(" ") %>%  
  unlist %>% 
  extract(1)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Assuming you mean `magrittr::extract`, this is likely to clash with `tidyr::extract`. Best to be explicit about which package you want to use in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is the 100% magrittr way to do it:

```
library(magrittr)
strings %>% strsplit(" ") %>% extract2(1) %>% extract(1)
```

`extract` is just an alias for `[` and `extract2` an alias for `[[`, so you can also do this :

```
strings %>% strsplit(" ") %>% `[[`(1) %>% `[`(1)
```

Though in most cases this form will often be more readable :

```
strings %>% {strsplit(.," ")[[1]][1]}
```